# Inherits from TextBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, inheritance, textbox

I am trying to create a new WPF control called **NumericTextBox**.

It inherits directly from **TextBox**.

I added a new DependecyProperty called **NumericValue** that it could be used to bind a numeric property.

Now, I would like to override the behavior of the **TextProperty** so that it could be accessed only as **ReadOnly**.

Is it possible redefine its behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that i'm aware of, readonly DependencyProperties must be defined as such using the seperate DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly() method, you can not change a property to readonly after it's been defined. You can only override the metadata: things like callbacks, default value.

Comment: Thank you,I am working to let the control works both with NumericValueProperty binding and also with TextProperty.